# Jacobians in two variables

Tags: calculus

In the $xy$-plane, draw the region $R$ bounded by the lines
$$
y = 1 + x, \quad y = -1 + x, \quad y = -1 - x, \quad y = 1 - x.
$$

1. Use a double integral in rectangular coordinates to find the area of $R$.
2. Use a double integral in polar coordinates to find the area of $R$.
3. Use simple (planar) geometry to confirm the answers (**1** and **2**) are correct.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Math.SE.  I edited your question to include $\LaTeX$ markup.  (You can view the edits to see what that looks like.)  You will get better answers if you say a bit about what you've tried.  Where exactly are confused?

Answer (score 1):

1. $R=\int^1_0 \int^{1-x}_{x-1}\,dy\,dx+\int^0_{-1} \int^{x+1}_{-x-1}\,dy\,dx=1+1=2$
2. $R=4\int^{\pi/2}_0 \int^{1-cos(\theta)}_{0}\,r dr\,d{\theta}$=2
3. Just calculate the area of R geometrically. $R=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$